# Creating Image copy Elasticsearch Running in Azure

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, cloud

We are running Elasticsearch cluster in azure cloud VM. We have more than 10 nodes. With Master nodes and HOT, WARM nodes. For security we are using Nginx instead of X-Pack. We need to install and configure in each and every node. Instead of installing and configuring all the settings again and again in each node. Can we install in a single node and take image snapshot of it and create more nodes ?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but... if you're running a VM, you can take a snapshot of the vhd and use that for creating new vhd's. FYI this question would fit better on SuperUser, not Stack Overflow (though, when posting there, you should include more information; as posted this is a bit unclear and broad).

Comment: @David Makogon, Updated the question broader, Can you check now ?

Comment: This is still a fairly broad question - I already mentioned that you can do snapshots but, if you're looking to automate deployments, there are probably better tools for the job (aside from Azure's built-in ARM templates, there are several commercial tools designed specifically for deployment purposes). But again... this would fit on SuperUser (or possibly ServerFault), not here.

Comment: Have you considered AKS? You can then use a single container for data, master and whatever other nodes you need. You can define your deployments as required and future scaling is pretty simple.